# Migrating site using A record and avoiding naming conflict

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, migration, a-record

A client has their new website hosted on our server, the new site however is under a different name to their domain name, as we hold developed sites on a subdomain. They want to load the new website from our hosting without impacting their existing email set up. I understand this should be done by pointing the A record  on their domain to us, however this is where I start to get a bit fuzzy.

I find that as the website is under a different name in our account the A record won't pick up this site. To get around this I ran a find and replace to match the site names, this however still didn't fix the issue, so I also created an alias for the subdomain as the actual domain name. This seems to have worked, however I'm curious as to if there's a better way to migrate a site in this way? Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do or what you've done but changing the A record for the website should have no bearing on their email. If you're thinking that you need to change the NS records or the MX records, you don't and shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thoughts as @[joeqwerty](https://serverfault.com/users/19152/joeqwerty) - changing the A record *should* not have any impact on email.

That, however, would only be true if the correct [MX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) records were in place, and (ideally) if a valid A/PTR pair was in place for the mail server (I am assuming the singular from the concern over the one A record).

Per [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321), by way of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record):

> - SMTP clients must look up an MX record;

- if (and only if) no MX record for the domain is present, treat the domain as if it had an MX record with the given domain as the target hostname and a preference value of 0
- perform A or AAAA lookups as required to determine the IP address of the target hostname

I suspect what you are referring to in your question is having set something up like:

```
example.com IN A 1.1.1.1
```

And wanting to change that - which shouldn't be an issue, so long as you also have your MX looking something very vaguely like:

```
example.com IN MX 10 smtp.example.com
```

And a suitable record for your MX host:

```
smtp.example.com IN A 1.1.1.1
```

You *might* need to adjust the host name accordingly on your mail server, too.

There is no fundamental reason the hosts in your MX records need to be within the same domain, either - you could perfectly well have them point to a mail provider's hosts, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the MX record entry (or entries) is/are, and if they are referencing the main domain and/or the www host in that main domain.

IF their MX is pointing at mail.example.com and mail2.example.com then simply pointing the A record for www.example.com and example.com to your IP would work without messing with mail.

If they do not have an MX record, one can be created and still send mail to wherever it ends up currently.

The problem will be if the MX record is pointing at the example.com host or www.example.com host.  If that is the case, the MX record needs to be updated to point to an A record that points to the machine currently getting all the mail, using a name like "mx.example.com" or "mail.example.com" or whatever is appropriate.  Once that is done and mail continues to flow, THEN the A record for example.com and www.example.com can get updated.

Assuming you are using Apache Name Based Virtual Hosts, then once they are ready to point www and example.com to your IP you need to (re)configure the virtualhost to respond to sub.example.com, www.example.com and example.com using the ServerName and ServerAlias directives.

If you aren't using Apache w/ NBVH then whatever process is equivalent.